# webclient appengine works locally but throws exception on Google Cloud appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-java-client

webclient oauth2 for accessing google drive by appengine works  on localhost appengine
but on google cloud app engine  throws exception.

```
       static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws IOException {

    Log.info("in initializeFlow oauthUtils");
    return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT_REQUEST,
            JSON_FACTORY, getClientSecrets(), PERMISSION_SCOPES)
           getClientSecrets().getDetails().getClientId(), 
             getClientSecrets().getDetails().getClientSecret(), 
           PERMISSION_SCOPES)

            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("online").build();
    }


       AuthorizationCodeFlow authFlow = initializeFlow();
               Credential credential = 
            authFlow.loadCredential(getUserId(req));


     drive = new Drive.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT_REQUEST, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    FileList result = null;
```

> ```
>     try {
>                     result = drive.files().list()
>                 .setPageSize(10)
>                 .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
>                 .execute();
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         Log.severe("for filelist");
>         throw new IOException("not able to get files from service 
>        OAuthUtils.getDataFromApi()");
>     }
> ```

with client_secrets.json

```
    {"web":{"client_id":"1006959462162-qmlxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"ggledrvsrvcaccntxxxxxxxx","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"Z-GUR_uf2hfh_seMz","redirect_uris":["https://ggledrvsrvcaccnt.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler","https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback","http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback","https://ggledrvsrvcaccntxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/oauth2callback"],"javascript_origins":["http://localhost","http://localhost:5000","https://ggledrvsrvcaccntxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com"]}}
```

here is the exception on google cloud appengine

```
         result = drive.files().list()
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .execute();
```

and throws exception.

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException:
>   401{"code" : 401,"errors" : [ {"domain" : "global",
>         "location" : "Authorization",
>
> "locationType" : "header", "message" : "Invalid Credentials", "reason"
>   : "authError" } ], "message" : "Invalid Credentials" } at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>   at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>   at
>   com.jagdiv.webapplication.backend.OAuthUtils.getDriveService(OAuthUtils.java:120)
>   at
>   com.jagdiv.webapplication.backend.OAuthUtils.getDataFromApi(OAuthUtils.java:404)
>   at
>   com.jagdiv.webapplication.backend.DriveServlet.doPost(DriveServlet.java:88)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) at
>   com.google.api.client.extensions.servlet.auth.oauth2.AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet.service(AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet.java:130)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:145)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:644)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:604)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:574)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
>   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:238)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

code link
https://github.com/RupamShaw/GogleApplication/tree/master/backend/src/main
  Note: on localhost access screen to select emailid comes but selection screen of emailid doesnt come when on googlecloud appengine.
Please help for correction.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exception and stack trace.